# Bing maps and monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, bing-maps, bing-api

I'm wondering if there's any SDK/control to use bing maps with monotouch? or probably any solutions on how to use iOS bing SDK with monotouch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chris Hardy has created MonoTouch bindings for Bing maps. Check it out [here](https://github.com/chrisntr/monotouch-bindings).

Comment: Thanks, looks like exactly what I need. will try to get it to work in my monotouch project!